# RDLC Hyperlink Report Viewer Report Definition Client Web reporting .Net Relative Path

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services, reportviewer, rdlc

I have a web project and I am using the webforms report viewer.  I created some local reports.  All I want to do is link one of the columns on the report to a query string clientID that will navigate to a local page within the website and on that page I will request the query string of the the ClientID and load that client.

="https://devserver002/MyWebsite/Reports.aspx?ClientID="&Fields!ClientID.Value & "&Key=2"

I have created an Go to URL Action on the textbox of that column the URL above.

This works it reloads the reports.aspx the clientID is requested and the client is loaded.

The Problem

How do I create this link to go to just a local page within my website without specifying the server within the address?  ="https://devserver002/

Currently its on a development server and it will be transferred over to a production server.  Its bad programming to put the server name within the URL because if you change servers the program is now broken.  How could I navigate without specifying this server within the URL using these reports?

Within the Report RDLC XML the link that works is

```
                      <ActionInfo>
                        <Actions>
                          <Action>
                            <Hyperlink>="https://devserver002/MyWebsite/Reports.aspx?ClientID="&amp;Fields!ClientID.Value &amp; "&amp;Key=2"</Hyperlink>
                          </Action>
                        </Actions>
                      </ActionInfo>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple, create a DNS A record on your local DNS server.  If you're going to use it on the internet, then you will have to register a domain name and create a DNS A record.

However, if it only a Intranet, you just have to add the record to your local DNS server.  If you not, you might have to create a hosts record on all your client workstation(worst case).

In addition, don't use the "" in your coding.  Just root operator (~).
For example:

```
"~/Reports.aspx?ClientID="&Fields!ClientID.Value & "&Key=2"
```

In addition, you can always use the loopback IP of 127.0.0.1 instead of the server name.

Comment: Your answer is way off.  This has to do with RDLC Reports.

Comment: Aren't you trying to hide the servername? You can  also use the loop back IP: http://127.0.0.1/

Comment: I am not trying to hide the server name I am just trying to not use the server name in my hyperlink and have it work.  I have tired "~/Reports.aspx?ClientID="&Fields!ClientID.Value & "&Key=2"  but then the column in the report will not act as a hyperlink unless I put the server name and make it into the whole URL path.  It seems like there should be a way around this.

Comment: Try the loop back then, instead of servername, replace with 127.0.0.1

Comment: I tried replaced the server name with 127.0.0.1 that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

> "https://devserver002/MyWebsite/Reports.aspx?ClientID="&Fields!ClientID.Value & "&Key=2"
> and this
> "https://127.0.0.1/MyWebsite/Reports.aspx?ClientID="&Fields!ClientID.Value & "&Key=2"

Should not make a difference.

Try this:

> https://localhost/MyWebsite/Reports.aspx?ClientID="&Fields!ClientID.Value & "&Key=2"

Addition:

Take a look at this link, [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7997822/rdlc-report-hyperlink-are-not-working-in-browser).  Here is a video that might help you too: [Click here to see video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iCAyWZwIaA4)

Comment: Doing this at least makes the column a hyperlink and you could click it but it navigates to This didn't work at all. It goes to a different server 127.0.0.1 not the current server and I get a 404 error page not found

Comment: try replacing the 127.0.0.1 with localhost.  See my updated answer.

Comment: No that didn't work either.  I spent the day on this no luck.  I don't know why  its not straight forward to use the Relative Path. Changing servers causes issues if I have to hard code the server name and application path

Comment: Why don't you you create a report parameter to hold the url, and use an expression for the url property.

Comment: The video they hard coded the localhost into the hyperlink and it is showing how to do a query string.  I replied to that parameter answer yesterday that was posted in 2011 so I am not sure if the user is still active.  I have tried several things to make it work but was unsuccessful.